# Pattern match with R

Tags: r

I am trying to match a pattern using `rgep()` function as below -

```
grep("XYZ31__Sheqwqet1__CSV.csv", "^(XYZ)+[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z_]+(csv)+$")
```

However unfortunately above expression results in no match. Any pointer towards the right direction will be very helpful.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the `csv` there is also a `.` and some digits.  In addition, the order of arguments is `pattern`, followed by the input `x`.  (if we pass arguments via name, the order wouldn't matter though)

```
grep( "^(XYZ)+[0-9]{2}[[:alnum:]_.]+(csv)$", "XYZ31__Sheqwqet1__CSV.csv")
#[1] 1
```

---

Pattern match is

- `^`- start of the string
- `(XYZ)+` - one or more occurence of those letters
- `[0-9]{2}` - two digits
- `[[:alnum:]_.]+` - one or more alpha numeric characters including the additional two
- `(csv)$`- csv at the end of the string